# ICalendar recurring event starts first day of month, ends last day of month, repeats every month

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

Using rfc5545 is there a way to represent an event that starts on the first day of each month and ends on the last day of each month and repeats every month?

It's slightly different than a daily repeating event which is not ideal for my use case.

Comment: The problem is the varying durations.  One could do 
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180301
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20180401
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1

but then google calendar for example does an overlap after the 30 day months and a big overlap in february.   May we ask what your use case is? there may be another way to think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: No

This is driven by the fact that the [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.6) clearly states that an event cannot have a month duration, only days, weeks or seconds.

> **3.3.6.  Duration**
>
> [...] Note that unlike
> [ISO.8601.2004], this value type **doesn't** support the "Y" and "M"
> designators to specify durations in terms of years and months.

(emphasis mine)